# Stack unable to locate Haskell executable to copy to docker container

Tags: docker, haskell, haskell-stack

When I run `$ stack image container` I get the following error:

```
Note: 'executables' not specified for a image container, so every executable in the project's local bin dir will be used.

Warning: The project's local bin dir contains no files, so no executables will be added to the docker image.
```

Here is my cabal file:

```
name:                haskell-gae
version:             0.1.0.0
synopsis:            Simple project template from stack
description:         Please see README.md
homepage:            http://github.com/githubuser/haskell-gae#readme
license:             BSD3
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Author name here
maintainer:          example@example.com
copyright:           2010 Author Here
category:            Web
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable haskell-gae
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Main.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5,
                       scotty,
                       aeson
```

Here is my stack.yaml:

```
resolver: lts-11.9
packages:
- '.'
extra-deps: []
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []

docker:
    enable: true

image:
  container:
      base: "fpco/ubuntu-with-libgmp:14.04"
      name: "testimg"

      entrypoints:
        - haskell-gae
```

`$ stack build` runs with no errors

`$ stack build --copy bins` gives this error:

```
Couldn't find executable haskell-gae in directory /home/coder/Nextcloud/Projects/haskell-docker/app/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-dkda49f7ca9b244180d3cfb1987cbc9743/lts-11.9/8.2.2/bin/
```

I did a search for the haskell-gae executable and found this:

`sudo find / -name haskell-gae`

```
/home/coder/Nextcloud/Projects/haskell-docker/app/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-dkda49f7ca9b244180d3cfb1987cbc9743/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/haskell-gae
/home/coder/Nextcloud/Projects/haskell-docker/app/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-dkda49f7ca9b244180d3cfb1987cbc9743/Cabal-2.0.1.0/build/haskell-gae/haskell-gae
```

Notice that the folder locations it is checking for the exe are different. No idea how to fix this and get `stack image container` to produce a docker image with the compiled executable running. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the Cabal copy step is failing.  Can you post the verbose log?  What is your stack version - perhaps there is a newer release?